# Change Button Function After html site loaded on Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have an application in which I loaded .html file inisde a iframe on button click.
[image]

On In Progress Click app inside .html file loaded in iframe.

[image]

Above picture is of Iframe. On click Close a pop up appear.

[image]

Now I want to override the functionality of this CLOSE MODULE Button.
For example: On click this button i want to reload the parent application.

I have tired below code but its not working.

```
$('.notify-popup-prompt-button').on('click',function(){
console.log(123);
location.reload("https");
})
```

Comment: `location.reload()` will reload the iframe content itself.. it should be `window.parent.location.reload();`  as the javascript is inside the iframe and from within the iframe you need to refer the parent window and reload it.

Comment: is the iframe src on the same domain? if not then you can't modify its content

Comment: Yes from same, but plugins are not

Comment: My code is not working so I cannot reach to location reload

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by changing in JavaScript using by .htlm file.